# Swift 5.3, how to safely assign value of type 'Int?' to type 'Int16'?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Having issues importing some JSON into CoreData using Swift 5.3

Here's the cut down struct:

```
struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    let code: Int?
}
```

The CoreData class property:

```
# MyClass
@NSManaged public var code: Int16
```

```
let newItem = MyClass(context: moc)
newItem.code = structItem.code 
// cannot assign value of type 'Int?' to type 'Int16'
```

or

```
if structItem.code != nil {
  newItem.code = structItem.code as! Int16
  // Cast from 'Int?' to unrelated type 'Int16' always fails
}
```

What I'm looking for is a safe way to import items like these as Int16, the JSON data source is not under my direct control and may conceivably change.

Disclaimer: I'm new to Swift, been putting off the move from Objective-C but now seems as good a time as any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
newItem.code = Int16(structItem.code)
```

Instead of:

```
newItem.code = structItem.code as! Int16
```

Comment: I was just about to answer myself here :)
```
if newItem.code != nil {
  newItem.code = Int16(structItem.code!) // I get an error that it must be unwrapped, which I assume it is by now and safe to do..
}
```

Comment: Be afraid of using force cast, it will be better to write
guard let code = newItem.code else { return }
code = Int16(structItem.code)

Comment: I'm suitably terrified. 
guard and return isn't really an option, am looping through quite a few structs with about 20 properties.

if structItem.code != nil {
  newItem.code = Int16(structItem.code ?? 0) // feels better
  newItem.code = Int16(structIten.code!) // ! required as I still get an error
}

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to decode the value as `Int16`

```
struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    let code: Int16?
}

...

let newItem = MyClass(context: moc)
newItem.code = structItem.code ?? 0
```